# Tensorflow: make custom Conv2d Layer with custom gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, layer, backpropagation

I'd like to have a Conv2d layer, that is able to return a gradient with values at certain indices multiplied with 0.2. The original functionality should remain.

My idea was to subclass the Conv2d class and have a setter method to save the indices where the groundtruth is 0:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class BackpassFilter(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, kernel_initializer, num_filter=48, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding='same', name='keypoints_3_4'):
    super(BackpassFilter, self).__init__()
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_initializer, num_filter, kernel_size, stride, padding, name, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)

    def call(self, input):
        return self.fc(input)

    def add_filter_indices(self, ground_truth):
        self.tmp_indices = tf.where(tf.equal(ground_truth, 0))

    @tf.custom_gradient
    def custom_gradient(self, x):
        ...
```

I have found that @tf.custom_gradient is something I could use. How can I implement the method to access the original gradients, manipulate and return them? Do I have to register the custom gradient somehow to be used in the class?